# Python-Django Response the text of error

Tags: python, ajax, django

How can I response the text of validation error to my template with Ajax?

```
def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        is_super = True
        if request.POST.get('is_super') in 'false':
            is_super = False
        if request.POST.get('password') == request.POST.get('confirm'):
            user = User.objects.create(first_name=request.POST.get('first_name'),
                                       last_name=request.POST.get('second_name'),
                                       username=request.POST.get('username'),
                                       is_superuser=is_super,
                                       date_joined=datetime.now())
            user.set_password(request.POST.get('password'))
            user.save()
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords doesn't match")
        return HttpResponse('')
```

Comment: The first thing to do IMHO would be to learn how to properly use forms and  forms validation in a view and how to make all this work __without__ ajax.  Once you'll get the canonical (no ajax) case working it will be time to wonder how to make it work with ajax too.

Comment: You shouldn't raise validation errors in the view. You raise them in the form, and the view sends the form - complete with `errors` attribute - to the template.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        is_super = True
        if request.POST.get('is_super') in 'false':
            is_super = False
        if request.POST.get('password') == request.POST.get('confirm'):
            user = User.objects.create(first_name=request.POST.get('first_name'),
                                       last_name=request.POST.get('second_name'),
                                       username=request.POST.get('username'),
                                       is_superuser=is_super,
                                       date_joined=datetime.now())
            user.set_password(request.POST.get('password'))
            user.save()

        else:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'error': True, 'message': 'Password and confirm password doesnt match'}))`            
        return HttpResponse('')
```

You need to show the above error message "Password and confirm password doesn't match" in HTML using Jquery.